# Syncrhonizing data between 2 systems through SQL query - bad or good practice?

Tags: sql, oracle, lotus-domino, data-synchronization

I have 2 systems, and I need to synchronize data in those systems daily.

First system is built on Oracle DB (let's call it ORACLE), and the second is built on IBM Notes\Domino (let's call it LOTUS).

Synchronization is one-sided, I only need to get some data from ORACLE and put it into LOTUS.

For now, I have the View in ORACLE, that produces all the data I need to put into LOTUS (about 20 000 rows * 20 columns), and on LOTUS side I have the scheduled Agent, that reads this View and processes data from it.

So, is it good or bad practice to sync data like this? What bad consequences may I face? Maybe it's better to create some SOAP service on ORACLE side that would return data in standartized way?

Comment: in the way you describe it is seems OK, if you need more complexe solution take a look at: LEI (Lotus Enterprise Integrator): http://searchdomino.techtarget.com/tutorial/An-introduction-to-Lotus-Enterprise-Integrator-LEI

Comment: If you include your actual code and ask for comments on specifc parts, rather than general advice we might be able to get the question re-opened. What I can tell you right now, though, is that it's definitely a bad practice if you delete and rewrite all the documents on the Lotus side every time the agent runs. There are always ways to avoid that, but a lot of people don't bother and they end up with millions of deletion stubs and badly fragmented databases that perform poorly.

Answer (score 1):

A scheduled agent that reads/writes data per SQL in Oracle is the usual way to go. Don't make it more complicated.